# Compute $E\left[\frac{W_{N(t)+1}}{N(t) + 1}\right]$ where $(N(t))$ is a homogenous Poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

> Let $W_1,W_2, \dots$ be the arrival times of a Poisson process $\{N(t) : t \geq 0\}$ of rate $\lambda$.  Calculate $$E\left[\frac{W_{N(t)+1}}{N(t) + 1}\right].$$

My attempt: Let $S_n$ be the sojourn time between the $n$-th and $(n+1)$-st arrivals, then
\begin{align} 
E\left[\frac{W_{N(t)+1}}{N(t) + 1}\right] &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty E\left[\left.\frac{W_{N(t)+1}}{N(t) + 1}\right|N(t)=n\right]P(N(t)=n)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty E\left[\left.\frac{W_{n+1}}{n + 1}\right|N(t)=n\right]P(N(t)=n)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty E\left[\left.\frac{W_{n}+S_n}{n + 1}\right|N(t)=n\right]P(N(t)=n)
\end{align}
Conditioning on $N(t)=n$, $W_n=\mathrm{max}\{U_1,\dots,U_n\}$ hence $E[W_n|N(t)=n]= tn/(n+1)$. Due to independence $E[S_n|N(t)=n] = E[S_n]=1/\lambda$, so the sum evaluates to
\begin{align} 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty E\left[\left.\frac{W_{n}+S_n}{n + 1}\right|N(t)=n\right]P(N(t)=n) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n+1}\left(\frac{tn}{n+1}+\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)\frac{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^n}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{tne^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^n}{(n+1)!(n+1)}+\frac{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^n}{\lambda(n+1)!}.
\end{align}

I don't know if there are any flaws in my argument leading up to the wrong calculation but I have been stuck trying to simplify the first summand. If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be great, thanks!

Comment: The trouble with your argument is that, conditionally on $N(t)=n$, $S_n$ is not exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$. Actually $S_n$ is biased towards its large values since once conditions in particular on $W_n+S_n\geqslant t$. To solve the exercise, note that $W_{N(t)+1}-t$ is the waiting time until the next renewal event after time $t$, which, by the lack of memory property, is exponential with parameter $\lambda$. Thus, $$E\left[\frac{W_{N(t)+1}}{N(t) + 1}\right]=\left(t+\frac1\lambda\right)E\left[\frac{1}{N(t) + 1}\right]$$ and the expectation on the RHS is straightforward.

Comment: Thanks, Didier! That definitely cleared things up. I have two follow up questions though, hope you don't mind.
1) Shouldn't the condition be $W_n+S_n > t$ (strict inequality) because otherwise it means $W_{n+1} = t$, which implies $N(t)=n+1$?  2) How to solve this problem when $N(t) + 1$ is replaced by $N(t)+k$ when $k \geq 2$? Let's say $k=2$, we define $t'$ as the time such that $N(t')=N(t)+1$ then $W_{N(t)+2} - t'$ is exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda$. How to proceed from here?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Which modified problem exactly?

Comment: I was talking about this: Calculate $E\left[\frac{W_{N(t)+2}}{N(t)+2}\right]$.

Comment: $$E\left[\frac{W_{N(t)+k}}{N(t)+k}\right]=\left(t+\frac{k}\lambda\right)E\left[{}{}{}{}\frac{1}{N(t) + k}\right]$$